# Multiple OnClickListner for a button

Tags: android

I am trying to make a countdown app. I have a button which starts countdown on pressing also the countdown text will appear on the same button too. so when user press again I want pause the countdown and hide text on button and if user press button again the countdown will start and text will show again.

So the question is how can I do multiple OnClick event for one button?
I tried the below code but only one `onClick` is  working and if I press again it never go on second `onClick`.

```
play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             //something
   }
        });

 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             //something
   }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That's not going to work. Use one listener then use a variable to check the "state" of the button or you could even check the text of the button to know if you should start/stop.

Comment: It's not a "state of the button". Button just reflects the state of something else, a service, a media player, etc. And does an action according to some external state, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners are overwritten. So just use two different ones, and set them according to the state.

```
public void onCreate( ... ){
    Button mButton = ...
    mButton.setOnClickListener( startListener );

}

View.OnClickListener startListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick( View v ){
       // start countdown
       // show text

       mButton.setOnClickListener( stopListener );
    }
}

View.OnClickListener stopListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick( View v ){
       // stop countdown
       // hide text

       mButton.setOnClickListener( startListener );
    }
}
```

Or you can use only one listener and change the behaviour depending on a variable

```
public void onCreate( ... ){
    Button mButton = ...
    mButton.setOnClickListener( listener );

}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick( View v ){

        if ( isRunning ){ 
           // start countdown
           // show text
        } else { 
           // stop countdown
           // hide text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the first solution. It's sort of separates 2 functionalities into 2 different objects rather than having to write a weired if and else. However, 2nd solution is better in performance wise if you have some statements common for both the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

use on listener and use a boolean variable to check if the countdown is running. you can set the boolean var true or false and then check it in an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for it.I doubt that's what you really wanted.

```
List<OnClickListener> listeners = Arrays.asList(
  new OnClickListener { ... },
  new OnClickListener { ... },
  new OnClickListener { ... },
  ...
);

play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    for (OnClickListener l: listeners) {
      l.onClick(v);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean flag.

For example, it can be written as follows:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         if (isCountDown) {
             ...hide count down text
             isCountDown = false;
         } else {
             ...show count down text
             isCountDown = true;
         }
    }
});
```